# How Can i get the text of DropDown with the value using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Hi all i have an dropdown which has some options with values

```
      <select id="displaytype">
      <option value="1002">TextBox</option>
      <option value="1003">CheckBox</option>    
      </select>

   var value="option value like(1002)" want the text of this value
```

now i have one of the values of the dropdown using this value,i should get the text of the value from the dropdown can any one help me here

Answer (score 1):

To get the text of an option, rather than its value, you can use the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

To get the text of the selected option you could use the [`option:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector:

```
$("#displaytype option:selected").text();
```

If you want to get the text of a specific option, you could use the [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector or [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method, to select the element at a certain index (zero based):

```
// Get the text of the first option in the select list
$("#displaytype option:eq(0)").text();
$("#displaytype option").eq(0).text();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3p4kZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use text() for selected option to get the select text.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/cbbWz/1/)**

```
alert($('#displaytype').val());                 //for getting selected item value 
alert($('#displaytype option:selected').text()); //for getting selected item text
```

To go through all the options and getting their text() you can use [**each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/cbbWz/2/)

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#displaytype option').each(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});​
```

​

Answer (score 0):

if you want value of the dropdown :

```
$('#displaytype').val();
```

and if the text of selected option:

```
$('#displaytype option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

If option is not selected but you want to get text by value:

```
$('#displaytype option[value=1002]').text();
```